# Record video iphone and play a sound

Tags: iphone, avfoundation

How i can record video and play a sound at the same time? I am having trouble doing so. I am using AVFoundation

Answer (score 0):

Set audio session category to `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord`?